# Which pins on a PiFace are positive/negative/ground?

Tags: piface

I am brand new to electronics, and have found it to be very difficult to find any documentation on the PiFace that is geared for noobs

I have a schematic for a reed switch to connect to an Raspberry Pi, as part of a home made security system. In this schematic, the connections are from the 3v3 (top left pin) and the ground (3rd pin from the top, on the right). But I have no idea where these pins are on the Piface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a PiFace, but there is a PiFace_Get_Started.pdf (at least on the Element14 site). I don't think you will find a 3.3v connections, because inputs and outputs are 5v.

To connect a reed switch, connect from one of the input pins to the common pin.